# CURL ignores hosts / apache config

Tags: php, apache, curl

This is a weird problem: a vhost in apache has been configured on my local machine in order to accept request like http://dev.myproject.com - my hosts file consists of a corresponding entry, e.g.

```
127.0.0.1 dev.myproject.com
```

Now, if I use the URL http://dev.myproject.com in my browser everything works like expected, i.e. index.php will be executed.

However, if I start my console and use

```
curl http://dev.myproject.com
```

it seems to ignore the entry in my host file, i.e. it tries to find http://dev.myproject.com using DNS resulting in

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: dev.myproject.com
```

Any ideas? I'm stuck...

Comment: Has already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390549/set-curl-to-use-local-virtual-hosts

Answer (score 3):

use the --resolve flag on your CURL command