# Tell cURL to read hosts file

Tags: php, curl

We are running nginx on CentOS 6.4 and upgraded the curl packages from 7.19 to 7.41 yesterday and since then cURL no longer checks the hosts file to resolve host names (and so will not connect to xyz.local)

We use cURL via Guzzle and are no longer able to connect to the various services on our local machines.

[John Hart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/260371/john-hart) posted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390549/set-curl-to-use-local-virtual-hosts/10218482#10218482) which is helpful but would require a fairly significant change to how our site (a LOT of legacy code) manages connections for our local and dev environments.

Is it possible to just tell cURL to use the hosts file?

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can install a DNS server that reads your hosts file, and use it as system DNS resolver. For example dnsmasq does this by default.