# Is there a curl command to do an inline hosts file replacement for that command?

Tags: curl, dns, hosts, service-discovery

I'm testing a service-discovery tool, and I'd like to test dns entries that will point to it before I set them up.

Ordinarily I'd do that by:

1. adding them to the `hosts` file,
2. running the `curl` command, and then
3. removing them from the `hosts` file.

The thought occurs I should be able to do this inline with `curl`.

My question is: **Is there a `curl` command to do an inline hosts file replacement for that command?**

EDIT:
I believe this is not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390549/set-curl-to-use-local-virtual-hosts?rq=1) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390549/set-curl-to-use-local-virtual-hosts/10218482#10218482) as I'm asking a different question that happens to have the same answer.

Comment: Effectively duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390549/set-curl-to-use-local-virtual-hosts?rq=1 and the specific answer is `--resolve` *if* you have (or get) a recent version of curl.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set cURL to use local virtual hosts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390549/set-curl-to-use-local-virtual-hosts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For part of this you actually want to test dns using `dig`.

The benefit of this is you can specify the dns server and the host you're trying to resolve.

```
dig @127.0.0.1 -p 8600 web.service.consul
```

Where `@127.0.0.1` is the dns server parameter and `web.service.consul` is a service configured on the dns server, consul.  Then pass the resulting IP address to your curl command.

To answer the original question - you want to [pass a header](http://www.cdnplanet.com/blog/how-test-your-cdn-before-go-live/) using `curl`

```
curl -H 'Host: static.example.com' http://dnsserveripaddress/
```

Some kind gents have pointed out `--resolve`

But it is looking like I [actually needed](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html)

```
curl --dns-servers
```

Note that this has [issues on OS X](https://curl.haxx.se/mail/archive-2015-04/0020.html). There appears to be [a workaround](https://verynomagic.com/2015/07/multiple-dns-resolvers-in-os-x.html), but I couldn't get that working.

It might even be that you start your own dns server, and then point your machine to that dns server.